# scale image on browser resize

Tags: actionscript-3

I am wondering how would I scale an image on browser resize with minimum and maximum width and height parameters?

I know how to use the Event.RESIZE function to make my image proportional with the browser using stage.stageWidth/Height, but I am trying to figure out a way to have a movieclip or image scale up or down to a certain dimension such as on browser resize the image max would be 640x480 and the minimum being 320x240. Anyone have a link or any suggestions? I can't find any forum with the exact answer. Thanks.

Comment: You probably want to accept the answers of a few of your previous questions if you want more people to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Math.min() and Math.max() to clamp the values for your width and height. I'm assuming you want the image to scale proportionally.

```
var w : Number = Math.max(320, Math.min(stage.stageWidth, 640));
var scaleRatio : Number = w / 640;
var h : Number = 480 * scaleRatio;

myImage.width = w;
myImage.height = h;
```

Comment: Thanks this is a great start for me. Question? How is this in relation to a stage that is 1024 x 768 because once I test, the resize doesn't happen until about halfway into lowering the browser size?

Comment: That would work the same, simply replace `640` with `1024` and `480` with `768`.